# Sorting a Dict whose values are objects Python

Tags: python, list, object, sorting

I have a `dict` in which the values are `list`s of `Object`s.

I need to sort them based on one of the object's attributes.

```
{key1 : [(list1 of obj),(list2 of obj),(list3 of obj)], key2 : [(list1 of obj),(list2 of obj)]}
```

I need to sort the `list` of values by one of the attributes, e.g. "Quantity".

My code structure is:

```
for objlist in mydict[key]:
    sorted(objlist ,key=lambda k: (k.Quantity),reverse=True)
    sorted(objlist , key=operator.itemgetter)
    s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
    objlist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("Quantity"), reverse=False)
    objlist.sort(key = lambda x: x.Quantity)
```

I tried all the above options but nothing worked.

Comment: `sorted` returns a new list, which you are not capturing.  What is the class of `Quantity`?  It need to be a class with the comparison operators implemented.

Comment: Also I need the sorted values should be a object as well. Since I will be using the attribute name

Comment: You are not iterating through the values, try your last one with `for objlist in mydict.values()`

Comment: I didn't get  " What is the class of Quantity? It need to be a class with the comparison operators implemented". Basically my dictionary is a output of a sql query which has key and studentID and values as one complete row of the sql output. one of the column in the table is Quantity which is a attribute in that object. I need to sort using that

Comment: that object is a pyodbc object

Comment: If I change to mydict.values() it is giving me attribute error. the Object list changing to normal list which i dont want "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Quantity'
"

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a simple type with an attribute, instead of making us try to talk around the vagueness in ways that are just going to confuse you?

Comment: OK, I'm misunderstanding the question then.  I don't know pyodbc objects, but you can only sort objects that can be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code for you

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,q):
        self.Quantity = q
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Class Test: Quantity=" + str(self.Quantity) + ">"
mydict = mydict = {"a":[ Test(3), Test(2), Test(4)], "b": [Test(8), Test(10), Test(6)], "c":[Test(14), Test(12), Test(20)]}
print "Before Sort"
for key in mydict:
    print (key,mydict[key])


dict_with_sorted_list = {}
for key in mydict:
    dict_with_sorted_list[key] = sorted(mydict[key], key=lambda k: k.Quantity, reverse=True)
print "After Sort"
for key in dict_with_sorted_list:
    print (key,dict_with_sorted_list[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply assigning the sorted lists back to the original dictionary, you can also use the list object's `sort()` method to sort each list in place and avoid creating a new list.  The usage is similar to `sorted()`.  Because you're not creating a new list, the `sort()` method is a hair faster than using `sorted()`.  In practice, it won't generally make much difference, unless you find a need to optimize and this is a pinch point.

```
>>> # Python 3.x
... from random import randint
>>>
>>> class Test(object):
...     # Borrowed from the accepted answer.
...     def __init__(self, q):
...         self.Quantity = q
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<Class Test: Quantity=%d>" % self.Quantity
...
>>> keys = 'a b c'.split()
>>> my_dict = {key: [Test(randint(0, 50)) for _ in range(3)] for key in keys}
>>> print("Before sorting:")
Before sorting:
>>> for key in keys:
...     print("%s" % my_dict[key])
...
[<Class Test: Quantity=13>, <Class Test: Quantity=49>, <Class Test: Quantity=9>]
[<Class Test: Quantity=30>, <Class Test: Quantity=3>, <Class Test: Quantity=6>]
[<Class Test: Quantity=29>, <Class Test: Quantity=33>, <Class Test: Quantity=37>]
>>> for key in keys:
...     my_dict[key].sort(key=lambda k: k.Quantity, reverse=True)
...
>>> print("After sorting:")
After sorting:
>>> for key in keys:
...     print("%s" % my_dict[key])
...
[<Class Test: Quantity=49>, <Class Test: Quantity=13>, <Class Test: Quantity=9>]
[<Class Test: Quantity=30>, <Class Test: Quantity=6>, <Class Test: Quantity=3>]
[<Class Test: Quantity=37>, <Class Test: Quantity=33>, <Class Test: Quantity=29>]
>>>
```